# AngularJS : Variables in ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model

I have a loop ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="data in datas">
Name: {{data.name}} <input type="text" ng-model="age">
</div>
```

I want `$scope.age` become to `$scope.age_data.name`. Eg: *$scope.age_Tan*, *$scope.age_Jim*...
So i have tried `ng-model="age_{{data.name}}"` but it make error.
How to solve this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The "right" way to do this is to, in the controller, do this:

```
$scope.ages = {};
```

Then in the template:

```
Name: {{data.name}} <input type="text" ng-model="ages[data.name]">
```

Should work...

Comment: Wow. You know Vietnamese? :)

Comment: Enough Vietnamese to order phở at any roadside stand along Route 1, but not much more.  I hope to spend a few months in Danang at some point and really learn the language.

Comment: Well. Nice to meet you. Thank you again :). I hope, i can meet you in real life. :)

Comment: What if it's a deep object?

Answer (score 1):

What you show here won't work exactly here's a couple of options

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MyCtrl', function() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.datas = [{
      name: 'thing1'
    }, {
      name: 'thing2'
    }, {
      name: 'thing3'
    }];
  })
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MyCtrl as myCtrl">
  Option 1
  <div ng-repeat="data in myCtrl.datas">
    <input type="text" ng-model="data.age" />
  </div>

  <br/>
  <br/>Option 2
  <div ng-repeat="data in myCtrl.datas">
    <input type="text" ng-model="myCtrl.age[data.name]" />
  </div>
  <pre>{{myCtrl|json}}</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to keep age of a person in another object/container. Here is the solution which may help you rethink you design.

```
$scope.people= [
  {name: 'Tan', age: 20},
  {name: 'Jim', age: 21}
];

<div ng-repeat="person in people">
Name: {{person.name}} <input type="text" ng-model="person.age">
</div>
```